# Cadastrar dados em uma tabela com chave estrangeira

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Eu estou tentando cadastrar um usuário porem na tabela dele há uma chave estrangeira ligada a outra tabela.

Meu problema é que essa chave estrangeira está referenciando a tabela endereço, só que eu ainda não tenho endereço para este usuário, eu quero que ele possa cadastrar depois quando desejar.

O que eu posso estar fazendo no momento do cadastro ?
Já tentei deixar o valor padrão como `null` e 0 mas não deu muito certo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu banco tem a necessidade de ter um relacionamento desse tipo?

Veja só, o mais correto seria você ter um relacionamento de Usuários para Endereços `1:N`, ou seja um *Usuário* pode ter mais de um *Endereço*.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dessa forma não teria a necessidade de você inserir um Id de endereço na tabela de *Usuários*.

Mas se isso deve ser da forma que você esta criando então suponho que você tem uma tabela de endereços já cadastrada em seu banco (Base dos Correios) por exemplo, mesmo assim seria um relacionamento **ruim**, *não teria o Nº da rua ou como informa outro endereço caso seja necessário.*

Se realmente você precisar criar seu banco da forma que esta falando então não use o Id do endereço definido como *not null*.

Comment: Perfeito cara, MUITO OBRIGADO ! exatamente essa lógica de que eu precisava. Obrigado !

Answer (score 2):

Pedro, isso está acontecendo porque a sua foreign key por padrão é definida como `NOT NULL`.

O que você deve fazer é alterar a coluna da foreign key para aceitar `NULL`. Como eu não tenho conhecimento da sua tabela, seria algo parecido com isso.

```
ALTER TABLE usuario MODIFY endereco_id INT NULL;
```

Eu não tenho certeza porque não estou com o ambiente com MySql aqui, mas talvez você tenha que dropar a contraint da sua foreign key, modificar ela para aceitar NULL e depois adicionar o constraint novamente.